# Ethereum Signature Information

Tags: signature, ecdsa

I am currently working with Ethereum Signatures (ECDSA and r, s ,v values) and I'm looking for official information about the recovery id v.

A few posts like this one explain how the calculation is done and I've already achieved to calculate this id. Now I wanted to find some official documentation on this, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything on how to calculate this. I know that it was taken over mostly from bitcoin but they have some more flags (compressed / uncompressed public key) which are not used on Ethereum.

Any help to find some source would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md

Comment: Do you already checked the Appendix F of the yellow paper? https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf In the appendix there are a couple of references that can help you out.

Comment: Here is a cryptographic explanation how the parameters r, s, v are derived https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38909, so we have v in the 0..3 range. The yellow paper will limit valid r, s so the possible values are only in the 0..1 range. The values serialized 27 y 28 en bitcoin, or 35+2*Networkid are arbitrary.